# javascript How to get two toggles on a page to work independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

Hi i currently have two toggles, one is on the sidebar and one is in the main body. They currently work together which is annoying, even though i am using to different scripts. The scripts i am using at the moment for the toggles are almost identical, however, even when using completely different scripts they still work together.

what i mean by work together is when i click the toggle on the main body the side bar toggle reacts.
They are toggles which collapse on oclick.

```js
<script>
        var divs = ["Menu", "Add"];
        var visibleDivId = null;

        function toggleVisibility(divId) {
            if(visibleDivId === divId) {
                visibleDivId = null;
            } else {
                visibleDivId = divId;
            }
            

            hideNonVisibleDivs();
        }

        function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
            var i, divId, div;

            for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                divId = divs[i];
                div = document.getElementById(divId);

                if(visibleDivId === divId) {
                    div.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    div.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // set up the click event
            $('.body > a').on('click', function(){
                $(this).next('div').siblings('div:not(#Menu)').hide("1");
            });
            // trigger orders which has id francc, not orders // .show("1") goes between $(this).next('div') + .siblings 
            // if i want a transition
            $('#Menu').trigger('click');
            // options include >>>, but it's slower // $('a[name="account"]').trigger('click');
        });
                
    </script>

   <!--  sidebar  toggle-->
    <script>
        var divs = ["Order", "Rest", "Franc"];
        var visibleDivId = null;

        function toggleVisibility(divId) {
            if(visibleDivId === divId) {
                visibleDivId = null;
            } else {
                visibleDivId = divId;
            }
            

            hideNonVisibleDivs();
        }

        function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
            var i, divId, div;

            for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                divId = divs[i];
                div = document.getElementById(divId);

                if(visibleDivId === divId) {
                    div.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    div.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <!--    Change color on click-->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('.sidebar h3').on('click', function() {
                $('.sidebar h3').css('color', 'black');
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            });
            $('h3#open').trigger('click');  //Your account red on page load
        });
    </script>


    <!--Your account toggle open on load    -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // set up the click event
            $('.sidebar > a').on('click', function(){
                $(this).next('div').siblings('div:not(#Franc)').hide("1");
            });
            // trigger orders which has id francc, not orders // .show("1") goes between $(this).next('div') + .siblings 
            // if i want a transition
            $('#francc').trigger('click');
            // options include >>>, but it's slower // $('a[name="account"]').trigger('click');
        });
                
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">

            <!--             Orders toggle-->

            <a  id="order" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Order');"><h3 id="orderr">Orders</h3></a>
            <div id="Order" style="display: none;">    
                <div>
                    <ul class="tabs">
                        <li id="order" class="Red"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">Overview</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!--Restaurant toggle-->
            <a id="restt" class ="header"href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');"><h3>Your Restaurants</h3></a>
            <div id="Rest" style="display: none;"><div>

                    <ul class="tabs">
                        <!--                    <li id="order" class="rred"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">restaurant</a></li>-->
                        <li id="order" class="rgreen"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">New restaurant</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>



            <!--            Account toggle-->
            <a id="francc" name="account" class ="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Franc');"><h3 id="open">Your Account</h3></a>
            <div id="Franc" style="display: none;">
                <div>
                    <ul class="tabs">
                      <li id="order" class="Blue" ><a href="admin_panel.php">Order History</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id=body>
            <!--    Menu toggle      -->
            <div class="container_head">  <!--            red header top of container-->
                <a  id="Menu" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Menu');"><h3>Menu Section</h3></a>
            </div>
            <div id="Menu_form" style="display: none;">   

                <form id="MenuForm" action ="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">
<!--                    <div class="field">-->
                        <label for="Name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Steaks pattern="[a-zA-Z]" 
                               required tabindex="1">
                        <br>

                        <label for="Description">Description</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description" placeholder="Fresh USDA Choice steaks, seasoned with hickory-smoked sea salt." tabindex="2">

                        <br>
                        
                         <div class="field">
                    <input type="submit"  value="Save">
                </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                                                      <a  id="add_prod" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Add');"><h3>Orders</h3></a>
            <div id="add" style="display: none;">    

            </div>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unqiue.

Comment: please remove any code that isn't relevant to the issue. Also confusing as to why you seem to have duplication of the same function declarations. A live demo with minimal css would be helpful

Comment: You need to give your functions unique names. How do you know which one you are triggering otherwise?

Comment: You can't just put a script twice in a page and expect it to work... Which tells me you don't really understand what the script is doing.

The other problem with this code is that you are storing the currently visible item in a single global variable. This means you can't have two accordions on the same page (this is usually called an accordion, yes). You could store the data in class, name or data-attributes instead.

Comment: They have unique names ime menu, order, francc etc :s. The ids are only there for trial and error and will be deleted at a later date. I am new to this so no i am not so clued up the reason im asking for help

Answer (score 0):

Bringing together @j08691 and Leo Farmer's comments, you need to have unique IDs and function names.  When you call `toggleVisibility(...)`, it's going to call the second declaration of that method.  Also, when you call `document.getElementById(...)` on something like "order", it's going to stop at the first instance it finds (In your case, the `a` tag).

Give your functions unique names, give your items unique IDs (if you want them to all do the same thing, you can look at using the same *class* for each item), and you should be in a better spot.

Comment: Hi thanks. They do have unique names i.e order, franc and menu. The toggle calls these

Comment: Each *element* needs to have a unique ID. That means you can't have an `a` tag, a `div` tag, and a `li` tag all with the same ID.